# Peeling Skinny Pig Skin

Tags: diet, grooming, skin-condition, skinny-pigs

I have just recently got a skinny pig about 3 weeks ago. I have done lots of research on what to do and how to take care of him and I thought I was doing a good job till I got home yesterday from work and noticed he had really dry skin. It almost looked like when we get sunburns and your skin starts to peel. I have only bathed him once without soap and I used a sensitive skin baby wipe on him once, I had put on a bit of baby oil because he had a dry patch but not a lot. So I purchased coconut oil and tried that last night because I thought maybe he had a reaction to the baby oil, but he is still very dry. So I guess my question is how do I help his skin and prevent this from happening again?